# Apparent Bug In SMS Authentication: Auth panel not showing any telephone # to choose from

Tags: docusignapi

It appears that SMS authentication does not function correctly 
when invoked via an envelope submitted in XML namespace
http://www.docusign.com/restapi. When attempting to sign
the SMS auth panel is shown minus any of the telephone numbers 
provided. I recast the envelope in JSON and the facility worked as 
expected. The panel and code are shown below. Please note that 
the code is derived from one of the api walkthrough samples
requestSignatureDocument.java. The only addition relates to SMS
Auth and is highlighted in yellow.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please post an image on an external site and I'll edit it in for you.

Comment: Here are two links to the aforementioned images [link](http://www.deltaanalytix.com.s3.amazonaws.com/xfer/CaptureSmsPanel.PNG) and [link](http://www.deltaanalytix.com.s3.amazonaws.com/xfer/CaptureSMSCode.PNG)

Comment: I heard back from docusign engineering. The fix is as follows: replace <senderProvidedNumber>someNumber</senderProvidedNumber> with <a:string>someNumber></s:string> where namespace a is xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays'

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer from comments for the benefit of the community.  From the sample XML image in your post, replace `<senderProvidedNumber>someNumber</senderProvidedNumber>` with `<a:string>someNumber></s:string>` where namespace `a` is `xmlns:a='schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays';`